# Python version of JS's x = variable || DEFAULT_VARIABLE?

Tags: python

I'm finding myself using hasattr a lot and would like to write more concisely.

In JS, I use the following pattern often:

```
var x = variable || DEFAULT_VARIABLE;
```

What's the equivalent in Python?

Something better than this...

```
if hasattr(my_obj, 'my_key'):
  x = my_obj.my_key
else:
  x = 3
```

EDIT: Fixed a bug mixing up objects and dicts.

Comment: I don't think your example code works the way you expect. `d['a'] = 5; hasattr(d, 'a')` => `False`.

Comment: Your JS and python examples aren't the same sort of thing, and your Python won't work because you're checking for an attribute and then fetching a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about javascript and `hasattr`, I'm guessing this is a situation where `variable` is undefined. In Python, `hasattr` doesn't test for the presence of dictionary keys, it only tests for the presence of object attributes. Furthermore, there is no simpler way than `hasattr` to test whether an object has an attribute in Python, because unlike in javascript, variable names *must* be defined to be used. Therefore, to refer to a variable name that may or may not be defined, you must use a string.

That said, you could use the ternary operator + `hasattr` to write the test in one line:

```
>>> class F(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> f = F()
>>> f.foo = 5
>>> f.bar if hasattr(f, 'bar') else 10
10
>>> f.foo if hasattr(f, 'foo') else 10
5
```

This works because `f.foo` isn't even evaluated if `hasattr` returns `False`.

You could also define `f.foo = None` and use `or` as [Wooble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697816/python-version-of-jss-x-variable-default-variable/6697904#6697904) suggests in his comment.

To test whether a key is in a dictionary, say `if k in d:`, and to get a default value if `k` isn't in the dictionary, if that's what you want, see [S.Lott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697816/python-version-of-jss-x-variable-default-variable/6697836#6697836).

Answer (score 4):

```
x = my_dict.get('my_key', 3)
```

That seems clear: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Assuming, of course, that `my_dict` really is a dictionary.  The whole `hasattr` thing in the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=variable if variable else DEFAULT_VARIABLE
```

Don't remember if this works with all python versions...

Comment: `x = variable or DEFAULT_VARIABLE` is shorter, and works in Python 1+

Comment: judging by the javascript, that looks like what OP is looking for.  Actually, I'm sure OP knows what he's looking for. :P